# PL SQL Record Operations

Tags: oracle, plsql, record

Hi I am working on an academic assignment and need some help setting up records:

> Write a PL/SQL block to print information about a publisher.
>
> - Declare a PL/SQL record based on the structure of the `bk_publishers` table.
> - In the declarative section, use the `%ROWTYPE` attribute and declare the variable `publisher_record` of type `bk_publisher`.
> - In the executable section, get all the information from the `bk_publishers` table by `using publ_id` and put it in your record. Display the `publ_id` and `publ_name` from the record using a cursor for loop.

[Reference Database Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20RGZ.png)

So far I have been able to write a block that outputs the contents, but I don't know how to get the contents of the record to print.

Any insights would be very helpful!
Thanks

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF


DECLARE
TYPE bk_record IS RECORD
    (publ_id bk_publishers.publ_id%TYPE, 
    publ_name bk_publishers.publ_name%TYPE);
publisher_record bk_publishers%ROWTYPE;

CURSOR bk_cur IS
    SELECT * FROM bk_publishers;

BEGIN

    OPEN bk_cur;
    FETCH bk_cur INTO publisher_record;
    CLOSE bk_cur;

    FOR publ_no in bk_cur
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(publ_no.publ_id || ' ' || publ_no.publ_name);
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `RECORD` variable can hold the contents of a single row, so you have to display column values of individual rows within a loop.

```
DECLARE
     TYPE bk_record IS RECORD ( publ_id  bk_publishers.publ_id%TYPE,
     publ_name          bk_publishers.publ_name%TYPE );
     publisher_record   bk_publishers%rowtype;
     CURSOR bk_cur IS SELECT *
                      FROM bk_publishers;
BEGIN
     OPEN bk_cur;
     LOOP
          FETCH bk_cur INTO publisher_record;
          EXIT WHEN bk_cur%notfound;  --Condition to exit the loop.
          dbms_output.put_line(publisher_record.publ_id 
                     || ' ' || publisher_record.publ_name);
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE bk_cur;
END;
/
```